# Calling fnGetPosition on datatables.net throws "Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to get the position of a row in datatables using the following code

```
var table = $('#UserInformationTable').dataTable();
var row_id = table.fnGetPosition($('#row_' + id));
table.fnDeleteRow(row_id);
```

The `$('#row_' + id)` is returning a tr.

The `fnGetPosition` does not work. I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`table.fnGetPosition();` expects a DOM node and you're passing a jQuery object. Change it from:

`table.fnGetPosition($('#row_' + id));`

to

`table.fnGetPosition($('#row_' + id)[0]);`

Answer (score 6):

`fnGetPosition` expects a node, not a jQuery object. So try:

```
var row_id = table.fnGetPosition($('#row_' + id)[0]);
```